# how to make div scrollable with 100% height and width?

Tags: html, css

i have included one table 100% and 100%.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%"> 
    <tr height="100">
         <td>
            this is fixed height 100px
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
              <div style="height: 100%;width: 100%">
            remaining height for this td. and this div should be do only vertical scrolling without expanding the page size.
              </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

first tr height is fixed height 100px

remaining height for this second tr. and this tr contains a div with 100% height and width, this div should be do only vertical scrolling without expanding the page size.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, can you elaborate and make an edit?

Comment: So the bottom div should be scrollable, or what?

Comment: i have edited. 
first tr height is fixed height 100px

remaining height for this second tr. and this tr contains a div with 100% height and width, this div should be do only vertical scrolling without expanding the page size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuCq2/)**

There is no need to use `table`. Use `div` instead:

```
<div id="head">this is fixed height 100px</div>

<div id="body">
    Content
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#head {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}

#body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: pink;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

---

Full Page Markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <style>
            #head {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 100px;
                background: yellow;
            }

            #body {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                background: pink;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="head">this is fixed height 100px</div>
        <div id="body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He might not know what CSS is or how to use it. From the code he posted I think the best bet is to post the entire file.

Comment: @HenryHarris Thanks for your suggestion, I've added the entire HTML file :)

Answer (score 1):

With your demo link I was able to successfully see what your issue is.

You do not have the following code in your second `<div>`'s `style=""` tag.

```
white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden;
```

If you add it you should be up and running.

Comment: thinks for your answer, look at this demo. http://www.knowledgewalls.com/realtimejqueryeditor/height-and-width-100%-expading-page-size-and-table-size. if your delete  white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden; this properties then u can see proper size.

Answer (score 0):

Trye `style="height:auto; overflow-y:scroll"`

Comment: thinks for your answer, look at this demo. http://www.knowledgewalls.com/realtimejqueryeditor/height-and-width-100%-expading-page-size-and-table-size. if your delete  white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden; this properties then u can see proper size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `style="height:100%; overflow-y:scroll"`

Answer (score 0):

try like this `<div style="height: 100%;width: 100%;overflow-y: scroll;">`